# How to set a subfolder to be the root for an external domain

Tags: redirect, dns, cpanel

I have a test site where I have various projects, but I am publishing one project to be public and I need a domain for it, with no link to anything else. I want that domain to be the "root" for the other site.

For example
website.com/newsite
I want newsite.com to have that folder as its root and treating that as a toplevel root. How can I do this on cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Addon domains function in cPanel. Just add your domain name as addon and select the folder that has the project files as its root folder.

Comment: I just did this, but its effectively redirecting to the actual site. How can I mask the redirection so that /site1/stats.php shows up just as domain.com/stats.php

Comment: This might be a matter of website configuration. Are you using WordPress or Joomla or any other CMS or application? For example if it is WordPress, you need to change its URL to match the new domain.

Comment: I am using cpanel, and straight php coding